# Из-за чего возникает переполнение?

Tags: java, исключения

Программа для нахождения слов с заданными окончаниями.

По отдельности методы работают, но если я пытаюсь из метода readAndSend() передать строку в foundIndex(String read), то выдает ошибку

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

С чем это связано?

```java
  import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class JavaApplication31
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
          {
            Reader r = new Reader();
            r.wordAppend();
            r.wordEnd();
            //          r.readAndSend();
            String readMe = "р ых. ых, ах sах gых укусила ах ыыыыыы ых ";
            r.foundIndex(readMe);
            System.out.println("");

          }
    }

    class Reader
    {
        String allText = "";

        void readAndSend() throws IOException
          {
            Reader rr = new Reader();
            String fragment = "";
            int sum = 0;

            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("R.txt"), "Cp1251"));

                int ch;

                for (;;) {

                    ch = br.read();
                    if (ch == -1) {
                        break;
                    }
                    allText += String.valueOf((char) ch);

                    fragment += String.valueOf((char) ch);

                    sum++;
                    if (sum % 1000 == 0) {

                        rr.foundIndex("р ых. ых, ах sах gых укусила ах ыыыыыы ых ");
                        //           r.foundIndex(fragment);
                        //           System.out.println(fragment);
                        fragment = "";

                    }

                }

                br.close();
            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("tshtsht");

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

          }
        ArrayList<String> wordEnd = new ArrayList();

        void wordEnd()
          {
            wordEnd.add("ых");
            wordEnd.add("ах");
            wordEnd.add("ла");
            wordEnd.add("ся");

          }
        ArrayList<String> wordAppend = new ArrayList();

        void wordAppend()
          {
            wordAppend.add(" ");
            wordAppend.add(".");
            wordAppend.add(",");
          }

        void foundIndex(String read) throws IOException// получать строку
          {

            int addWordCount = 0;
            int countChangeEnd = 0;
            int goEnd = 0;
            int countArrayEnd = 0;

            String readMe = read;

            for (int indexEnd = 0;; indexEnd += 1) {

                indexEnd = readMe.indexOf(wordEnd.get(countArrayEnd) + wordAppend.get(countChangeEnd), indexEnd); // окончания + . или пробел 

                if (indexEnd == -1) {

                    if (countArrayEnd + 1 == wordEnd.size()) {

                        if (countChangeEnd + 1 == wordAppend.size()) {

                            break;
                        }

                        countArrayEnd = 0;
                        countChangeEnd++;

                        continue;
                    }

                    countArrayEnd++;
                    continue;
                }

                int indexStart = readMe.lastIndexOf(" ", indexEnd);
                System.out.println(indexStart + " // " + indexEnd);
                if (wordEnd.get(countArrayEnd).equals("ла") || wordEnd.get(countArrayEnd).equals("ли") || wordEnd.get(countArrayEnd).equals("ло")) {
                    System.out.println(readMe.substring(indexStart + 1, indexEnd + wordEnd.get(countArrayEnd).length() - 1));
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println(readMe.substring(indexStart + 1, indexEnd + wordEnd.get(countArrayEnd).length()));
                }
            }

          }
    }
```

Comment: Что за цикл for (int indexEnd = 0;; indexEnd += 1), зачем без условия прекращения? Уверены ли Вы, что break точно сработает?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С чистотой кода явные проблемы, но да ладно.

Проблема банальная, вы в основной программе вызываете функции заполнения массивов, а только потом уже вызываете свою функцию.

```
Reader reader = new Reader();
reader.wordAppend();
reader.wordEnd();
```

А в вашей функции вы этого не делаете и при попытке получить элемент из пустого списка закономерно получается ошибку [ArrayList -> get -> IndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)).

```
ArrayList<String> wordAppend = new ArrayList();
wordAppend.get(0)
```

Думаю так должно работать

```
...
rr.wordAppend();
rr.wordEnd();
rr.foundIndex("р ых. ых, ах sах gых укусила ах ыыыыыы ых ");
...
```

Comment: Вы правы, бесконечно правы